# How manage HTTPStatus with Thymeleaf switch in unique error page html

Tags: error-handling, thymeleaf, http-status-code-404

I created a custom controller to manage a different error:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyErrorController {


    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ErrorController.class);

    @ExceptionHandler(UpdatableException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public String indirizzoErrato(UpdatableException ex, final Model model) {
        logger.error("Indirizzo errato", ex);
        String errorMessage = (throwable != null ? ex.getMessage() : "Unknown error");
        model.addAttribute("errorMessage", errorMessage);
        return "error";
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(ReservedException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public String erroreServer(ReservedException ex, final Model model) {
        logger.error("Errore Server", ex);
        String errorMessage = (ex != null ? ex.getMessage() : "Unknown error");
        model.addAttribute("errorMessage", errorMessage);
        return "error";
    }

}
```

But I'd like to see different message (and images) based on the error from the HTTPStatus response in the unique page html named error:

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Indirizzo Errato</title>
<head>
        <title>Errore</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" th:href="@{/css/main.css}" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <img class= "404" src="/images/NotFound.jpg">    
    </body>
</html>
```

I don't when I run my code, on console I have this message: "ERROR 10212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat-7].[localhost]         : Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]"

Please can you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Change ${response.status} for ${#response.status}

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use custom error controller to show customize error message by your html page..

here i give my code for your help you can return different error page base on `statusCode` value .... or sent same error page and set message into html page

```
@Controller
public class CustomErrorController implements ErrorController {

    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public String handleError(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
        Integer statusCode = (Integer) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code");
        Exception exception = (Exception) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception");
        model.addAttribute("statusCode",statusCode);
        if(statusCode==404){
            model.addAttribute("imgSrc","/img/fotFound.png");
        }else if(statusCode == 500){
            model.addAttribute("imgSrc","/img/internallError.png");
         }
        model.addAttribute("errorMessage","Error code : "+statusCode);
        return "error";
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return "/error";
    }
}
```

and change your html code like below

```
<body>
    <img class= "404" th:src="${imgSrc}"> // set here your src which send form controller
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work the customization of the response.status (I want to watch different images based on different error of HttpStatus.response).

Comment: try it .....
if(statusCode==404){model.addAttribute("imgSrc","/img/fotFount.png");}

Comment: I rewrite my file html like you suggest me, but it doesn't work